# How to add my Ask Ubuntu Flair HTML code to blogger

Tags: blogger

I am about to launch a personal blog on blogger and I have been told I can add my Ask Ubuntu Flair code to my 'About me' column. I am a newbie to these HTML stuffs so how do I add this code to my blogger blog? If it helps I will be using a custom template and not the default ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly go to your Ask Ubuntu profile (by clicking your username on the top) and click on flair. Copy the HTML code. The go to the design page of your blog (`page elements` tab) and add a new gadget. Choose the `HTML/JavaScript` option and paste the flair code in there. You can move the gadget freely into every available space there. Note however that I'm unsure whether any custom template supports adding gadgets but it's worth a try.